# Fourier transform either changes sign infinitely often far out or is continuous at $x=0$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

I am reading a book ***"Fourier Series and Integrals" by Dym & McKean***.

There is an exercise (Page 106):

> **Exercise:** *Check that if $f$ is a real, even, summable function and 
>   if $f(0+)$ and $f(0-)$ exist, then either $f(0-) =f(0+)$ or $\hat f(\gamma)$ changes sign 
>   infinitely often as $|\gamma| \to \infty$.*

Note that $\hat f(\gamma)$ is a real function, so its "sign" makes sense!

There is a hint for the exercis as follow:

> **Hint:** The function $f$ is summable if it is of one sign far out, as you can see from 
>   $$\frac{f(0-) +f(0 + )}{2} = \lim_{t \to 0} \, (P_t * f) (0) = \lim_{t \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-2 \pi^2 \gamma^2 t) \hat f(\gamma) \, \mathrm{d}\gamma.$$ 
>   Here $P_t=P_t(x)=\dfrac{\exp(-\dfrac{x^2}{2})}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}$ is the Gauss Kernel and $P_t * f$ means the convolution of $f$ with Gauss Kernel.

My try:

If f is of one sign far out, then by using 
$$\frac{f(0-) +f(0 + )}{2} = \lim_{t \to 0} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-2 \pi^2 \gamma^2 t) \hat f(\gamma) \, \mathrm{d}\gamma,$$
and Monotone convergence Theorem we deuce that $\hat f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ so $$f(-x)=\hat {\hat f}, $$ is continuous and consequently $f(x)$ will be continuous at $x=0$ and therefore $f(0-) =f(0+)$.

I don't know how to handle the other half.

Thanks.

Comment: please don't post on different sites at the same time, it's a waste of effort --- http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2084541/fourier-transform-either-changes-sign-infinitely-often-far-out-or-is-continuous

Comment: Doesn't f being even already implies your claim?

Comment: The Gauß kernel is missing a $t$, it is $(2\pi t)^{-1/2}\exp(-x^2/2t)$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The exercise is stated in Dym and McKean with a mistake. The correct statement is

If $f$ is real, even, the finite limits $f(x\pm 0)$ exist for all $x$,
and $\hat{f}$ does not change sign for $|x|>A$, then $f$ is continuous at all points.

The statement is in the paper of M. Kac (1938) to which Dym and McKean refer. The proof is simple: inverse Fourier transform of positive function is continuous. If $\hat{f}$ is positive only for $|x|>A$, add to it the function
$h(x)=B,\; |x|<A$ and $h(x)=0$ otherwise, to make it positive everywhere. The inverse
Fourier transform of $h$ is explicitly computed and it is continuous.

Remark. The assumptions can be relaxed by saying that $f$ is real, even,
integrable, and  bounded in
a neighborhood of $0$.